# how to print new line in table row using tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

i tried the below code.

```js
        {
            "Topic": "If statement",
            "C": "if ( condition )\r\n   { code ;}\r\nelse if( condition )\r\n   { code; }\r\nelse \r\n   { code; }",
            "C++": "if ( condition )\r\n   { code ;}\r\nelse if( condition )\r\n   { code; }\r\nelse \r\n   { code; }",
            "JAVA": "if ( condition )\r\n   { code ;}\r\nelse if( condition )\r\n   { code; }\r\nelse \r\n   { code; }",
            "PHP": "if ( condition )\r\n   { code ;}\r\nelse if( condition )\r\n   { code; }\r\nelse \r\n   { code; }",
            "JS": "if ( condition )\r\n   { code ;}\r\nelse if( condition )\r\n   { code; }\r\nelse \r\n   { code; }",
            "PL/SQL": "if (conditio) then \r\n   {code;}\r\nelsif (conditon) then \r\n   {code;}\r\nelse \r\n   {code;}",
            "VBNET": "If condition Then\r\n    code\r\nElse If condition Then\r\n     code\r\nElse\r\n     code\r\nEnd If",
            "PYTHON": "if ( condition ):\r\n    code\r\nelif ( condition ):\r\n    code\r\nelse: \r\n    code"
        },
```

But new line is not showing.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB2La.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format#format-builtin):

> The ***textarea*** formater shows text with carriage returns intact (great for multiline text), this formatter will also adjust the height of rows to fit the cells contents when columns are resized.
>
> ```
> {title:"Example", field:"example", formatter:"textarea"}
> ```